# matching contents of an array with an array in xml using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I've seen similar problems but nothing that matches exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm building a product "wizard" where the user answers questions and the answers are currently stored in an array like so:

```
userAnswers = ['abc',xyz',gtd'];
```

The XML I'm trying to match against looks like this. (note: I can change this to json or change the format if there's a more efficient way way of doing this)

```
  <row>
    <answer1>abc</answer1>
    <answer2>xyz</answer2>
    <answer3>mta</answer3>
    <product numbers>productID, productID2, productID3</product numbers>
  </row>

<row>
        <answer1>abc</answer1>
        <answer2>xyz</answer2>
        <answer3>gtd</answer3>
        <product numbers>productID, productID2, productID3</product numbers>
</row>
```

Based on the array above it should match the 2nd row, at which point I would like to access the contents of the product numbers node. The dataset is not huge (5 questions max) but the number of possibilities can get up there. This also has to function within the memory constraints of the ipad. If it helps I'm using jquery mobile as a framework.

Thanks in advanace!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why 2 different formats (xml, json), if you said you can modify the format to whatever you like?

If i were you, i would do the following:

First transform the xml to a simple json like this:

```
var answers = [
    {
        answers: ['abc', 'xyz', 'mta'],
        products: [1, 2, 3]
    },
    {
        answers: ['abc', 'xyz', 'gtd'],
        products: [4, 5, 6]        
    }
];
```

Then:

```
var match = function(array1, array2){
    if (array1.length != array2.length)
        return false;

    for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
        if (array1[i] !== array2[i]){
             return false;   
        }
    }
    return true;
};

for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++){

    if (match(answers[i].answers, userAnswers)){
       console.log(answers[i].products);   
    }
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/wwLuM/

If you need further details, or want some modifications please let me know. Hope this helps

Comment: I probably should have explained that the original data is coming from Excel (business decision) and so I'm taking an exported CSV and doing the conversion. It can be xml, json or anything else that's suitable. The trick is creating a CSV that can then be converted to the format you're suggesting.

Comment: Your example worked. I realized I was looking at this problem the wrong way, create a good JSON file first and then convert that back to CSV. Thanks again!